# Python Simple Regression Plot

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python and I want to perform a simple linear regression on a .csv dataset.  I've successfully imported the data file. If I have data for 8 five year periods and I want to do simple linear regression how would I do this? The data is by county/state.  So my headers are county, state, 1980,1985 etc.. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many statistical libraries for python

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what target label you have in mind.
Anyways, use the sklearn library and pandas.

```
val= pd.DataFrame(your.data);
val.columns = your.headers;
```

Assuming you have a target header called "Price".

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = val.drop('Price',axis=1)
```

X contains the data on which LR will be performed.
Now create a Linear Regression object.

```
lm = LinearRegression()
```

Start the fitting:

```
lm.fit()
```

Predict your targets:

```
lm.predict(x)
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all real world problems that you are going to encounter will have more than two variables, so let's skip the basic linear regression example. Linear regressions involving multiple variables is called "multiple linear regression". The steps to perform multiple linear regression are almost similar to that of simple linear regression. The difference lies in the evaluation. You can use it to find out which factor has the highest impact on the predicted output and how different variables relate to each other.

In this section we will use multiple linear regression to predict the gas consumptions (in millions of gallons) in 48 US states based upon gas taxes (in cents), per capita income (dollars), paved highways (in miles) and the proportion of population that has a driver’s license.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
# %matplotlib inline

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/your_Path_here/petrol_consumption.csv')

    dataset.head()  

    dataset.describe()
```

Result:

```
       Index           ...             Consumption_In_Millions
count  48.00           ...                           48.000000
mean   24.50           ...                          576.770833
std    14.00           ...                          111.885816
min     1.00           ...                          344.000000
25%    12.75           ...                          509.500000
50%    24.50           ...                          568.500000
75%    36.25           ...                          632.750000
max    48.00           ...                          968.000000
```

Preparing the Data
The next step is to divide the data into attributes and labels as we did previously. However, unlike last time, this time around we are going to use column names for creating an attribute set and label. Execute the following script:

```
X = dataset[['Petrol_Tax', 'Average_Income', 'Paved_Highways',  'ProportionWithLicenses']]
y = dataset['Consumption_In_Millions']
```

Execute the following code to divide our data into training and test sets:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Training the Algorithm
And finally, to train the algorithm we execute the same code as before, using the fit() method of the LinearRegression class:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression  
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

As said earlier, in case of multivariable linear regression, the regression model has to find the most optimal coefficients for all the attributes. To see what coefficients our regression model has chosen, execute the following script:

```
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])  
coeff_df
```

Result:

```
                        Coefficient
Petrol_Tax               -40.016660
Average_Income            -0.065413
Paved_Highways            -0.004741
ProportionWithLicenses  1341.862121
```

This means that for a unit increase in "petrol_tax", there is a decrease of 24.19 million gallons in gas consumption. Similarly, a unit increase in proportion of population with a driver’s license results in an increase of 1.324 billion gallons of gas consumption. We can see that "Average_income" and "Paved_Highways" have a very little effect on the gas consumption.

Making Predictions
To make pre-dictions on the test data, execute the following script:

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

To compare the actual output values for X_test with the predicted values, execute the following script:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})  
df
```

Result:

```
    Actual   Predicted
29     534  469.391989
4      410  545.645464
26     577  589.668394
30     571  569.730413
32     577  649.774809
37     704  646.631164
34     487  511.608148
40     587  672.475177
7      467  502.074782
10     580  501.270734
```

Evaluating the Algorithm
The final step is to evaluate the performance of algorithm. We'll do this by finding the values for MAE, MSE and RMSE. Execute the following script:

```
from sklearn import metrics  
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Mean Squared Error:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))  
print('Root Mean Squared Error:', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Results:

```
Mean Absolute Error: 56.822247479
Mean Squared Error: 4666.34478759
Root Mean Squared Error: 68.3106491522
```

You can see that the value of root mean squared error is 60.07, which is slightly greater than 10% of the mean value of the gas consumption in all states. This means that our algorithm was not very accurate but can still make reasonably good predictions. 
There are many factors that may have contributed to this inaccuracy, a few of which are listed here:
1.  Need more data: Only one year worth of data isn't that much, whereas having multiple years worth could have helped us improve the accuracy quite a bit. 
2.  Bad assumptions: We made the assumption that this data has a linear relationship, but that might not be the case. Visualizing the data may help you determine that. 
3.  Poor features: The features we used may not have had a high enough correlation to the values we were trying to predict.

Note: the data set used in this example is available from here.

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/regression/x16.txt

Finally, see the two links below for more info on this topic.

https://stackabuse.com/linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn/

https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.06-linear-regression.html